# React set target value on onKeyUp

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can set the target value by using `e.target.value` on `onBlur` function, if we change `onBlur` to `onKeyUp`, there will be an error shown below:

> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

Since I am using React hook form, so I would like to solve this without using extra `useState`

```js
  onBlur={(e) => {
    e.target.value = formatFunc(e.target.value)
  }}
  onKeyUp={(e) => {
    e.target.value = formatFunc(e.target.value)
  }}
```

Comment: Could it be that, `onKeyUp`'s `EventTarget` does not have the prop named `value`. What happens if you `console.log` to view the list of available props on the argument `e` and on `e.target`.

Comment: Reference: [React Keyboard Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#keyboard-events)

Comment: @jsN00b you're right onKeyUp is different

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the key value in onKeyUp you should use `e.key`